# Is there any official way to use the "server push" with HTTP/2 as a long live push channel?

Tags: http2, server-push

Is there any official way to use the "server push" with HTTP/2 as a long live push channel? If so I can push data with the channel at any time.

Comment: Nope, push in HTTP/2 does not trigger any application-level callback, but is processed by the browser only. So, it cannot be used to push application data to the client. You need to use a WebSocket for that.

Comment: Thanks you all guys, I know now, we really can't use "server push" feature to send further data anytime.

Comment: Now, I'm working for learning gRPC that is what I want, which base on HTTP/2 has bidirectional stream to send further data anytime.